# Conjunction Choice: That, when or nothing

Tags: word-usage

Which of the following is preferred?

1- When was the latest time **when** you saw Alex?

2- When was the latest time **that** you saw Alex?

3- When was the latest time you saw Alex?

Please let me know if the answer differs between *oral* and *written* English?

Comment: It would certainly be wrong to repeat _when_. (2) and (3) mean the same - (3) is informal (it would be more usual to say _the last time_).

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for all the help!!!